# Stormpath failed to find resource

Tags: python, flask, stormpath

In order to authenticate in Flask with Stormpath, the user sends an access token in the request's header.

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <token_id>'
}
```

I validate it with:

```
authenticator = ApiRequestAuthenticator(application)
uri = 'bla_dont_care.com'
result = authenticator.authenticate(headers=request.headers, http_method='GET', uri=uri, body={}, scopes=[])
is_valid = result.account is not None
```

The authenticator is not being initiated in every request but saved in memory.

My response time raised from 40ms to 450ms.  I read that the Stormpath SDK caches the API calls specifically for this.

Trying to debug this, I did see that the cache get 2 misses per 1 request [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/cache/cache.py#L46).  The key it failes to find is `https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/VJiXDWTWnYdNgrFe9BoI3/accounts/6TGIMWF47DO0XUK96M07XEMG1`.  It fails to find the resource [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-python/blob/master/stormpath/data_store.py#L139).

What account is it looking for? `6TGIMWF47DO0XUK96M07XEMG1` is not the account sent.  How can I debug this?

Comment: I'll have to look at this in more depth. I'm at a conference at the moment, but will have time to investigate when I'm back!